# How do I have an autoscroll to the right on my text in Xcode (swift)?

Tags: swift, xcode

For example: [spotify-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joBRX.png)

If the name of a song is too long in spotify, it will automatically scroll to the right in order to show the full name of the song. I want to achieve something like this with Xcode (version 9), but I don't know how to do it. Currently trying with a textview.. but any help would be appreciated.

edit: I also want to disable manual scrolling of that text field. I want it to exclusively automatically scroll, and reset back to it's original place in some time, which would restart the process of scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you are looking for is **Marquee Label**. Check this [link](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel)

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!